# background-size:cover; zoom in/out effect

Tags: css, background, size, cover

I'm having an issue trying to use the `background-size:cover;` in css.

To explain:

When I have one div of width **100%** and fixed height, when I *control+* and *control-* in browser, the background image of that div is not fitted inside the div, it changes( a zoom in/out effect if I can say it like this ).

If I have a div of 100% width and another div( child of the first ) with fixed width and height and I set the background image with background-size: cover, that zoom in/out effect does not work.

I hope I explained OK, but let me show the problem in code.

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<style>
body
{
    background:red;
}


.test
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    background-image: url( 'http://bhodbuzz.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/6924750-mountain-wallpaper.jpg' );
    background-size: cover;
}

.test2
{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px auto;
}

.inner
{
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: 900px;
    height: 300px;
    background-image: url( 'http://bhodbuzz.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/6924750-mountain-wallpaper.jpg' );
    background-size: cover;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test2"><div class="inner"></div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

How to fix the problem ?

Comment: Zooming works for me on Firefox. What browser are you checking on, or what exactly do you mean by "not working".

Comment: read the answer below my post.

Comment: You should still clarify what you mean in your question.

Comment: I clarified in my example, Adam understanded. I dont know a better explaination.

Comment: A better explanation would be explaining what you mean by "does not work". What, *exactly*, happens that makes you come to the conclusion "this doesn't work"? Is the zoom function broken? Does the image disappear? Does it turn into a unicorn? Etc.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that your first div changes it's width depending on window size, so it zooms in/ zooms out your background image to fill the div. Your div `test2` has a fixed width, so the background won't 'zoom in' unless the background image is smaller than the div. I see the image you're using is full HD size and your div is just 900px wide. Take a look at the snippet below, used smaller image

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<style>
body
{
 background:red;
}


.test
{
 width: 100%;
 height: 300px;
 background-image: url( 'http://asset-d.soupcdn.com/asset/12360/7926_dcea_500.jpeg' );
 background-size: cover;
}

.test2
{
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0px auto;
}

.inner
{
 margin: 0px auto;
 width: 900px;
 height: 300px;
 background-image: url( 'http://asset-d.soupcdn.com/asset/12360/7926_dcea_500.jpeg' );
 background-size: cover;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test2"><div class="inner"></div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The effect still does not appear at the 2nd div. I understand the problem. What to do ? I need fixed size.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use width in your class.

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<style>
body
{
 background:red;
}


.test
{
 
 height: 300px;
 background-image: url( 'http://asset-d.soupcdn.com/asset/12360/7926_dcea_500.jpeg' );
 background-size: cover;
}

.test2
{
 
 margin: 0px auto;
}

.inner
{
 margin: 0px auto;
 width: 72.2%;
 height: 300px;
 background-image: url( 'http://asset-d.soupcdn.com/asset/12360/7926_dcea_500.jpeg' );
 background-size: cover;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test2"><div class="inner"></div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I know that. BUt i need fixed size, otherwhise, why i asked this problem ?

Comment: Then use  width using parentage. as width:80%

Comment: it works, but i need just 962. is there a posibility to determine in css how percent is 962 from the window width ? or i need to use js

Comment: width: 72.2%; you can use.

Comment: For all resolutions it will minimize according to window size. If you want it as fixed width like 962px then it will not be responsive.

Comment: i do not want responsive.

Comment: Use width width using parentage. width: 72.2%;  It will work for all device. I checked. if you use 962px it will not work according to your acceptation it will not be fixed it will be minimize .